# Hide Woocommerce variable subscription product price range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-subscriptions

I would like to hide the Subscription product variation details "From: $38.50 / month for 12 months and a $50.00 sign up fee" I need a code to disable.

I've tried other snippets which hide the word "from" or changed the verbiage of "sign up fee".

```
/*
 * Disable Variable Product Price Range completely:
**/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );

function my_remove_variation_price( $price ) {
    $price = '';
    return $price;
}
```

The code works only for default WooCommerce products but not with subscription products.

I expect *"From: $38.50 / month for 12 months and a $50.00 sign up fee"* to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hide the price range from variable subscription products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_html_for_variable_subscription', 10, 2 );
function hide_price_html_for_variable_subscription( $price, $product ){
    if ( $product->is_type('variable-subscription') ) {
        $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Your code working just fine. I have a question. Can we show the selected price only to there instead of completely hiding it ?

Comment: The selected price requires some javascript…